Matrix representation of Operator
I have a question about the matrix representation of an operator. My operator $\hat{X}$ is defined by the action on a function $u$ and is  given by
$$\hat{X}u=g\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}(U)\mathcal{F}(gu)\}\,\, .$$
In this equation $U$ is a known function and also the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is known. Further, I used $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ for the inverse Fourier transform. I have given the values of the function $g$ at discrete points $\{x_i\}$. Is it in this case possible to construct a matrix
$$X=g \mathbf{F}^{-1}\{\mathbf{F}(U)\mathbf{F}(g)\}\,\, ,$$
such that we can calculate the first equation in the case of finite differnces by $Xu$ (I used $\mathbf{F}$ for the discrete Fourier transform)? It looks like I have taken the $u$ out of the expression, which makes me sceptical that this is valid. However, I dont know how to formulate the operator $\hat{X}$ as a matrix.
Please note: I know that I can also formulate the first equation with the help of a convolution, but this is not what I want, because it is easier for me to work with $\mathcal{F}(U)$.
Thanks for helping, Birgit.

$F(gu) \neq F(g) u$
